# Can ADB be used to add a shortcut to the Launcher2 home screen on a rooted Nexus S?

Tags: android, android-emulator, launcher

More generally, are there any other ways to add home screen shortcuts besides manual user action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can ADB be used to add a shortcut to the Launcher2 home screen on a rooted Nexus S?

No.

> More generally, are there any other ways to add home screen shortcuts besides manual user action?

Only if you write your own home screen, or find some third party home screen that offers some sort of API.